# Trying to create objects within a for loop

Tags: javascript

I'm sure there's a really simple solution to this but I can't wrap my head around it. I'm trying to create and array of objects within a for loop like so:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    foos[i] = new Foo(i*10);
    bars[i] = someObject.createBar({
         x : 0,
         y : 0,
         foobar = function() {
              foo[i].a = true;
         }
    });
}
```

When trying to run this I get 'cannot set property a of undefined', both foos and bars are declared earlier in the code as globals.

It works fine if I create foos as foos[0] and access through bars[0]. I suspect it's something to do with function level scoping but as far as i can see the arrays should be accessible on the global object....

Comment: Is this just because you're trying to set foo[i].a rather than foos[i].a in the foobar function?

Comment: @dougajmcdonald Well seen. We all immediatly think about a closure problem but it may be just a typo...

Comment: Your syntax is invalid. `foobar = ` can't be used withing object literal notation

Comment: two typos there then! - it was the closure problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to "anchor" the value of `i`. To do this...

```
for(var i=0; i<100; i++) {
    (function(i) {
        // now do stuff with i
    })(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++) { 
    foos.push( new Foo(i*10) ); 
    bars.push( someObject.createBar({ 
         x : 0, 
         y : 0, 
         foobar = function() { 
              foo[i].a = true; 
         } 
    }) ); 
}
```

Comment: It's a scope issue within the `foobar` handler. Using `.push` won't help here.

Answer (score 0):

The value of i in the execution of foobar is the one at the end of your loop (100). Because the loop block is a closure.

You'd better store the value you want. For example :

```
for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    foos[i] = new Foo(i*10);
    bars[i] = someObject.createBar({
         x : 0,
         y : 0,
         i : i,
         foobar: function() {
              foos[i].a = true;
         }
    });
}
```

Or use a intermediate closure in your loop to enclose i :

```
for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    (function(i){
        foos[i] = new Foo(i*10);
        bars[i] = someObject.createBar({
             x : 0,
             y : 0,
             foobar: function() {
              foos[i].a = true;
             }
        });
    })(i);
}
```

The first solution is more explicit, the second one is maybe now more usual.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set value "a" of undefined, because "foo[i]" is undefined. You never defined foo[i]. Did you mean foos[i], maybe?

Also, as others have said, your function foobar is going to use the same value of i for every object you create. You should create a new closure with i, which will allow you to define a local variable i that can be different for each interior function, as so:

```
for(var i=0; i<100; i++) {
   (function(i) {
      // now do stuff with i
   })(i);
}
```